# Submit button redirecting to different address

Tags: php, html, forms, model-view-controller

So the submit button of this form is supposed to send the data to `localhost/mvc/contact/test` and redirect to `localhost/mvc/contact`

at the first click of submit button it works well

[Right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoVda.png)

but when I click the submit button again its taking me to `localhost/mvc/test`

[Not right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjHBT.png)

here is the html code of the form `<form action="test" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="contact">`

when I had this as `<form action="contact/test" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="contact">` it first redirected me to `localhost/mvc/contact` but on second attempt redirected to `localhost/mvc/contact/contact/test`

Btw it's a simple mvc framework you may check it out on github for more clarity on [Leggera @ Github](https://github.com/me-nkr/Leggera)

The above mentioned code is present on `view/contact/index.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these things:

1. You must give the full path to the file like `<form action="contact/test/index.html" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="contact">`
2. In the index file of contact/test you can use `<?php header("Location: http://www.example.com/");?>`  for redirection.
3. Maybe you have given wrong paths to files.

You must give more details for more specific answer

Comment: ok so this is a mvc framework that Ive been working on. here the `localhost/mvc/view/contact/index.php` is a hack file (html+php). `localhost/mvc/contact` calls the contact controller and `localhost/mvc/contact/test` calls the test method of contact controller which is a class

Comment: should I be giving path like the full url ?